# submit button not working correctly

Tags: forms

To fix the problem with the submit function 
I have tried clearing my cache
I have also tried uninstalling the module and reinstalling the module. the code segment is below.

The submit function for some reason never is run

```
function redirect_custom_reg_menu_alter(&$items) {
  if (isset($items['user/register'])) {
    $items['user/register']['page arguments'] = array('redirect_custom_reg_user_register_form');
  }
}

function redirect_custom_reg_user_register_form() {
  $form = array();

  // Add the form fields for the registration form.

  $form['personal']['username'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('username'), 
    // this is built in validation to the form api
    '#required' => TRUE, 
    // control the size parameter
    '#size' => 20,
    '#prefix' => '<div id="foo">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#description' => 'Please enter your first name',
    '#maxlength' => 25,
  );

  $form['name']['formtype'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => t('form type'),
    '#options' => array(
      t('form1 form'),
      t('form2 form'),
      t('form3 form')
    ),
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit',
  );

  return $form;
}

function redirect_custom_reg_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message(t('The form has been submitted. personal="@username"',
    array('@username' => $form_state['values']['username'] )));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your form function is called `redirect_custom_reg_user_register_form()`, so your submit function needs to be called `redirect_custom_reg_user_register_form_submit()`.

If you want to keep the same submit function name that you have currently, you need to add it manually in the form function as Drupal only looks for a function called `FORM_FUNCTION_NAME_submit()` by default:

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'redirect_custom_reg_submit';
```

Comment: I think I am starting to understand the Hierarchical  structure in Drupal.